# Перенос строки в Net::XMPP (perl)

Tags: perl, xmpp

Есть скрипт, который принимает аргументы переданные в него с помощью вызова bat.cmd
Первый аргумент - адрес, второй - тело сообщения.

В теле сообщения перебрал все возможные способы переноса строк,
.. и "text\n", и "text<\br>" и "textПЕРЕНЕСИСЬПЖЛСТА" - в окне жаббер клиента (QIP,Pidgin,JAJC) я получаю то, что отправил - "text\n". В случае с <\br> сообщение отправляется, но не приходит вообще.

НО, если в body => "text\ntext", то строка переносится без проблем.

Есть ли какая-либо возможность организовать перенос строки в теле одного сообщения? Заранее спасибо!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict; 

use utf8;
use Encode;

use Net::XMPP;
use Net::XMPP::Stanza;
use base qw( Net::XMPP::Stanza );

my ($recip, $msg) = @ARGV;

$msg=decode("cp1251",$msg);

if(! $recip || ! $msg) {  
    print 'Syntax: $0 <recipient> <message>\n';  
    exit;  
}

my $con = new Net::XMPP::Client();  
my $status = $con->Connect(  
    hostname => 'HOST',  
    connectiontype => 'tcpip',  
    tls => 0);  
die('ERROR: XMPP connection failed') if ! defined($status);  
my @result = $con->AuthSend(  
    hostname => 'HOST',  
    username => 'JID',  
    password => 'PASS'); 
die('ERROR: XMPP authentication failed') if $result[0] ne 'ok';  

my $message = Net::XMPP::Message->new();
$message->SetMessage(to => $recip, subject=> 'theme', body => $msg, type => 'chat');
$message->InsertRawXML("<html><body>$msg</body></html>");
$con->Send($message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После строки

```
$msg=decode("cp1251",$msg);
```

добавьте что то вида

```
$msg =~ s!\\n!\n!g;
```

и должно работать.

Comment: ДАЙ Я ТЕБЯ РАСЦЕЛУЮ ВДЁСНА :*************